# fetch records based on today's date

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I wish to generate reports for my application, one such report requires to display list of orders given today. For that I have the following method in my ejb which returns nothing (debugged and found so):

```
public Collection<OrderStock> getOrderReport(String userName) {
   String strQuery = null;
    strQuery = "Select o from OrderStock o where o.userName.userName = :userName and o.orderDateTime = :orderDateTime";

     Collection<OrderStock> c = em.createQuery(strQuery).setParameter("userName",userName).setParameter("orderDateTime", new Date(),TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();

   return c;
}
```

How do i solve it? Why does it return nothing?

**edited:**
I am using mysql as backend
datatype of orderDateTime is DateTime
eg os data in orderDateTime : 2012-06-05 00:12:32
                              2012-06-05 11:34:42
                              2012-04-05 12:32:45

Comment: Show us the data there is in the database, tell us the type of the orderDateTime column.

Comment: edited my question to include what you want...pls refer...

Comment: Then Joost's answer is the right one. Your query tests if 2012-06-05 == 2012-06-05 13:21:45.765, which is obviously false.

Comment: i know that. so what do i do to retrieve today's records?

Comment: You read Joost's answer.

Comment: yep i read it, but isn't there any other way?

Comment: Not in pure JPQL, because it would need a JPQL function such as toDate(), which doesn't exist: where toDate(o.orderDateTime) = toDate(:orderDateTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `DateTime` column, and are looking for posts on a single date. I suspect this datetime column contains seconds or miliseconds since the Epoch. You can't compare times to dates, so you will have to convert the day to a time. Actually two times that describe the day.

```sql
SELECT o 
FROM OrderStock o 
WHERE 
    o.userName.userName = :userName 
    AND (
        o.orderDateTime >= FirstSecondOfTheDay
        OR o.orderDateTime <= LastSecondOfTheDay
    )
```

Depending on your database system you can calculate these seconds (or milliseconds, i don't know your table) using the database or rather do it in java

Comment: thanks but is there any other way for eg. using jpa or jpql to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Date() as simple as that. The date persisted in the DB will definitely have different format. So the best thing to do is to look into the method used to persist the data in the first place and use the same method to fetch back the data.

The method might by Oracle function, java method. You need to investigate further into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for MySQL:

```
strQuery = "Select o from OrderStock o where o.user.userName = :userName and date(o.orderDateTime) = :orderDateTime";

Date today = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DATE);

Collection<OrderStock> c = em.createQuery(strQuery).setParameter("userName",userName).setParameter("orderDateTime", today ,TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```